# php exec puppeteer script no output

Tags: php, macos, puppeteer

I ran this script using php just to get the value it return but its blank.
if I run the node directly on command line it has a value. anything I am missing?

the code consists of scrapping a div inside a web page.

**Php**

```
<?php
$command = "/usr/local/bin/node /night/pup.js";
exec($command, $output, $return_var);
print_r($output);
//empty array
?>
```

**Terminal:**

```
/usr/local/bin/node /night/pup.js
//123456
```

**pup.js**

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

var weight_lb = 200;

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'],
});
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://xxx.xxx/xxx/x.html');

    await page.evaluate(function() {
        document.querySelector('#initialWeightField').value = '';
    })

    await page.type('#nothing', "1");

    const text = await page.evaluate(() => 
      document.querySelector('#finalWeightField').textContent);
    await console.log("success");
    await console.log(text);
    //Only for testing
    //await page.screenshot({path: 'example1.png',fullPage:true});
    await browser.close();

})();
```

Comment: you set options launch -> `const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ args: ['--no-sandbox', '--disable-setuid-sandbox'] });`  and show code file pup.js

Comment: updated the code

Comment: Please check `$return_var`, what value does it return?

Comment: it returns 0, it has something to do with permission i think, i have it on htdocs, and the puppeeter too. i think the permission on web is different that running in terminal

Answer (score 0):

> **Change from `.textContent` to `.value`**

```
const text = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('#finalWeightField').value);
```

Comment: textContent works, or is this specific when running on web or cli to execute?